# How to print values in dataframes column by their indexes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe:

```
id   value
742  aa
1711 bb
1731 qq
1799 ff
2741 pp
```

id is the index column. I want to print only those values from column "value" which are in this list: [742, 1731, 1799]. So the output must be:

```
aa
qq
ff
```

How to do that?

I tried this:

```
for i in [742, 1731, 1799]:
    print(df[df.index == i]["value"])
```

but the output is:

```
value
742    aa
Name: value, dtype: object
value
1731    qq
Name: value, dtype: object
value
1799    ff
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Comment: would you be able to share what you've tried to do so far?

Comment: @mrtig yeah sure, I added it in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-with-a-list-by-%60in%60-or-%60not-in%60-in-python) should do it:

Restating the problem:

```py
ids = [
    {"id":"742", "value":"aa"},
    {"id":"1711", "value":"bb"}, 
    {"id":"1731", "value":"qq"}, 
    {"id":"1799", "value":"ff"}, 
    {"id":"2741", "value":"pp"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ids)
df = df.set_index(["id"])
```

This gets you the filtered list:

```py
filtered_df = df[df.index.isin(["742","1731","1799"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.set_index` to declare `'id'` as the index, then `.loc[...]` to specify the list of indices you're interested in.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89], 'val': 'for sale baby shoes never worn'.split()}).set_index('id')

print(df)
#       val
# id       
# 8     for
# 13   sale
# 21   baby
# 34  shoes
# 55  never
# 89   worn

print(df.loc[[13,89]])
#      val
# id      
# 13  sale
# 89  worn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in df:
    if i.index in [742, 1731, 1799]:
        # print(i.value)
        # print(i["value"])
```